# Change Shell default color

Tags: gnome, themes, colors, gnome-shell

I wonder if there a way to change the brownie default color in Gnome shell to a more grayed one. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and applied the Arc dark theme with Gnome Tweak, but I think a more grayed color will looks more integrated:
[image: Example]

I found a way to change the default font adding a .css to .themes folder a selecting it from Tweak Tools, but don't know how to change the background color.

```
stage {
font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Arc supply a shell theme also along with the GTK theme? Choose Arc as the shell theme too using GNOME Tweaks, not just the application theme.

Comment: Yes you are right... didn't noticed that :)
Do you know where is the configuration file for tweaking the font style and size of that Arc Dark shell? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Well the solution is to change the font and size in the default Arc-Dark shell theme located in `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` i.e.

```
    stage {
  font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
  font-size: 11pt;
  color: #D3DAE3; }
```

Then select "Arc Dark" as the shell theme using GNOME Tweaks.